# Stripe one time setup fees on subscription on specific plans

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments

I want to charge one time setup fees to the customer when the first time a plan is subscribed

Suppose I have 4 Plans A,B,C,D so when user subscribe to Plan A or Plan B 
I want him to pay setup fees (extra amount 10 dollars more)

Please help me how it can be done using stripe API or even from the dashboard?

Answer (score 0):

Stripe documents how to create these one-time items on new Subscriptions [here](https://support.stripe.com/questions/add-a-one-time-fee-or-discount-with-a-new-subscription-plan). You'd need to perform the logic for which Subscriptions apply these on your own (for example, making the API call based on which Plan you're creating the Subscription for).

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but your answer is not even close to my query

Comment: Would you mind clarifying your question and/or comment to identify which portions are unaddressed? It appears to be a simple question but if there are additional requirements, I'd be happy to clarify!